# output of multi strings in php function

Tags: php, string, function

I want to take output these three strings, I use this code

```
function sectionString()
{ 

$section_a = 'Khan live in india<br/>';

$section_b = 'Khan live in Australia<br/>';

$section_c = 'Khan live in Pakistan';

return $section_a

return $section_b

return $section_c

turn $section_c
}
echo sectionString();
```

Here it output like this **Khan live in india** but I want to take output like this

**Khan live in india**

**Khan live in Australia**

**Khan live in Pakistan**

what i should shange in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate this strings into one:

```
function sectionString()
{ 

$section_a = 'Khan live in india<br/>';

$section_b = 'Khan live in Australia<br/>';

$section_c = 'Khan live in Pakistan';

return $section_a.$section_b.$section_c;
}
echo sectionString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not understanding the proper use of `return`. return will end your function and nothing beyond that line of code, within the function, will be executed. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Answer (score 1):

Once your code hits the first "return" it, well.. returns, which means no more of that function will process.  Put all three strings in one variable and return it.

Either an array (better) or just as a string with breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the first "return" that is hit during the execution of the function will stop the execution of the function and return its associated value.

If you want to return several sections, you could for example code

```
function sectionStrings() {
    $section_a = 'Khan live in india';
    $section_b = 'Khan live in Australia';
    $section_c = 'Khan live in Pakistan';
    $output = array($section_a, $section_b, $section_c);
    return $output;
}

echo implode("<br>", sectionStrings());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:--

```
function sectionString()
{ 
$a= array();
$section_a = 'Khan live in india<br/>';

$section_b = 'Khan live in Australia<br/>';

$section_c = 'Khan live in Pakistan';

$a[]=$section_a;

$a[]=$section_b;

$a[]= $section_c;
return $a;
}
print_r(sectionString());
```